# Bringing personal electronics to the US

Tags: usa, shipping

I am a German citizen and am going to have a 6-months internship in the US on a J-1 visa. I would like to take my personal computer rig with me, it consists of my MacBook Pro, two monitors and a few miscellaneous items, totalling around 5000-6000€.

I have the options of shipping them with e.g. FedEx or taking them with me on the plane in a second suitcase or submitting them as special baggage.

What do I have to be aware of with these two different approaches? Do I have to pay an import tax?

In addition, what do I have to aware of when returning home with these items?

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Sorry, wasn't aware of the expatriates community. Could a moderator move this question or do I have to manually repost it?

Comment: I flagged this for moderator attention (move to expat)

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't have a problem since they are for personal use and you are not *importing* them for commercial purposes.  However, convincing Customs on both sides might be a different matter.

Comment: Not recently, but I've heard of people registering expensive items with customs in their home country so that when they bring them back in, there's no issue. Perhaps [this form](https://www.formulare-bfinv.de/ffw/form/display.do?%24context=96B79F29E6CA0FF84918)....?

Comment: @mkennedy That link says "session expired".

Comment: Try this link: http://www.zoll.de/SiteGlobals/Forms/FormularMerkblattSuche/EN/FormularMerkblattSuche_BegriffSuche_solr_form.html and look for document 0350.

Comment: You bring the small, valuable, easy to pack things... the common, cheap, bulky things, you buy/rent them here.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely carry on everything you mentioned except for the monitors. There should be no tax on any of these personal belongings. Here's the [customs form](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/CBP%20Form%206059B%20English%20%28Sample%20Watermark%29.pdf) -- There are no questions about the value of personal effects. Only about commercial merchandise. You would be crazy to Fedex this stuff.